# Using PhpStorm is there a way to change a line of code on every file of a remote host?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, google-tag-manager

I am currently working on a project with over 50 HTML files. Each file has a google tag script implemented however the google tag is the incorrect one ex. `GTM-1234` but it should be `GTM-4321`.

The google tag was entered into the body and header of every page manually (it doesn't use an include or script from another file to inject the code into the header).

Is there a way to find and replace `GTM-1234` to `GTM-4321` in every file in the remote host directory?

I tried using the <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd> (Replace in Files) function, however the scope tag doesn't allow me to choose the remote host.

Comment: No. The IDE cannot do Find-and-Replace in remote files. They need to be part of the actual project files. You can try mounting your remote file system into local one (SSHFS or something like that) and then open the project from such location. But the speed will be low as the IDE needs to read/index all files (which means "downloading them" in this case). So if you want to do it using PhpStorm -- zip and download needed folders, expand them locally and work from there (upload them back when done).

Comment: If it has to be "all remote only" -- try some standard CLI tools (`grep` and alike) to do that in your remote terminal -- `GTM-1234` seems like an unique piece of text so should be no problem doing that.